# Is there any way to execute blocking code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, worklight-adapters

In specific, I'm making a call to the database which retrieves an aggregate value. This is then displayed to the user. But before the adapter call(since I'm using worklight) can complete,the code after that gets executed which is something that I want to block. I have tried everything from setTimeout to calling a function that executes an empty while loop. None of them seem to work as the code is skipping all of these too. Could someone please help me out with this?

Sample code:

```
var flow_completed_percentage=0;
function setFlowStatus()
{
    var flow_name,flow_status_value;

    for(var i = 0;i < 2; i++)
    {
        flow_name=flow_name_DB[i].trim();//flow_name_DB is an array that stores the flow names
        flow_status_value=flow_status_DB[i].trim();//flow_status_DB is an array that stores the flow status values

        if(flow_status_value=="R" || flow_status_value=="A")
        {
            var invocationData_totalPercentage = {
                adapter : "dummy_adapter",
                procedure : "getJobPercentage",
                parameters : [flow_name]
            };

            WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData_totalPercentage, {
            onSuccess : setPercentageSuccess,
            onFailure : setPercentageFailure
            });
        }
      }//end of for loop
     //the problem is next iteration of for loop begins before the adapter call for the current iteration completes.
     //So flow_name gets overwritten and it gives the wrong result.

    function setPercentageSuccess(total_percentage)
    {
      var tot_percent = total_percentage.invocationResult.resultSet[0];
      flow_completed_percentage=tot_percent.TOT_PERCENT;
      if(flow_status=="R")
        runningStatus(flow_name);
      else if(flow_status=="A")
        abortedStatus(flow_name);
    }

    function setPercentageFailure()
    {
       alert("Failed to fetch records from DB");
    }
}

function runningStatus(flow)
{
  //do something
}

function abortedStatus(flow)
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Javascript, in clients (browers) and servers (node.js) doesn't take kindly to things that block execution.

Comment: so there is no way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call the remaining block of code after the completion of you database operation.

Since have to perform the same operation number of times, you can call the function multiple times instead of using a loop.

I tried to change the code as follows: You can call the function with next value of `i` after the completion of database operation.

```
var flow_completed_percentage=0;
function setFlowStatus()
{
    var flow_name,flow_status_value;
    var initial = 0;
    iterator(initial); // initial call

    function iterator(i)
    {
        flow_name=flow_name_DB[i].trim();//flow_name_DB is an array that stores the flow names
        flow_status_value=flow_status_DB[i].trim();//flow_status_DB is an array that stores the flow status values

        if(flow_status_value=="R" || flow_status_value=="A")
        {
            var invocationData_totalPercentage = {
                adapter : "dummy_adapter",
                procedure : "getJobPercentage",
                parameters : [flow_name]
            };

            WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData_totalPercentage, {
            onSuccess : function() {
                setPercentageSuccess();
                iterateNext(i); // call next after DB completion
                },
            onFailure : function() {
                setPercentageFailure();
                iterateNext(i); // call next after DB completion
                }           
            });
        }
    }

    function iterateNext(current)
    {
        current= current+1;
        if(current<2){ // check the loop condition
            iterator(current);
        }
    }

    function setPercentageSuccess(total_percentage)
    {
      var tot_percent = total_percentage.invocationResult.resultSet[0];
      flow_completed_percentage=tot_percent.TOT_PERCENT;
      if(flow_status=="R")
        runningStatus(flow_name);
      else if(flow_status=="A")
        abortedStatus(flow_name);
    }

    function setPercentageFailure()
    {
       alert("Failed to fetch records from DB");
    }
}

function runningStatus(flow)
{
  //do something
}

function abortedStatus(flow)
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Yes,I am calling the remaining block of code after the completion of the database operation..the problem is I have a for loop in lets say DoMyThing() function and the next iteration executes before the database call completes..is there any way i can block that?

Comment: You need to post at least the pseudo code, so that I can understand the flow. Without that it is difficult to guess the problem.

Comment: I have edited my question..if you need anything else please let me know

Comment: I have edited my answer.It is sort of rough, but you can get an idea.